# How many homomorphisms from $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x,y]}{(x^3+y^2-1)}$ to $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(7)}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

How many homomorphisms from $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x,y]}{(x^3+y^2-1)}$ to $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(7)}$?

I already checked that $x^3+y^2-1$ has these five integer roots: $(-2,3),(-2,-3),(0,1),(0,-1)$ and $(1,0)$, so it is not an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}$.

The ring $\displaystyle \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(7)}$ is the same as $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{7\mathbb{Z}}$, right? Since $7$ will generate $7\mathbb{Z}$, so this ring $\displaystyle \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(7)}$ is a finite ring of $7$ elements. But then how can I find the number of homomorphisms? I am also failing to analyze the order of elements that will generate the domain ring.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z[x,y]/(f(x,y))$ to $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$
are the homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z[x,y]$ to $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$
which send to $f(x,y)$ to zero. 
The homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z[x,y]$ to $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ are the maps
$$\phi_{a,b}:h(x,y)\mapsto h(a,b)$$
where $a$, $b\in\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. So $\phi_{a,b}$ kills $f(x,y)$
iff $f(a,b)=0$. So the number of  homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z[x,y]/(f(x,y))$
to $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is the number of solutions of $f(a,b)=0$ over
$\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

In your example, you are counting the number of solutions of $x^3+y^2-1=0$
modulo $7$, so counting points on an elliptic curve.

Comment: Thanks! Wolfram shows these 11 solutions: $(0,1),(0,6),(1,0),(2,0),(3,3),(3,4),(4,0),(5,3),(5,4),(6,3),(6,4)$, so there are 11 homomorphisms. Do you know a good way to find these solutions? I only know how to find integer solutions of such equation by trial and error.

Comment: Remember cubes mod 7 are -1,0 or 1, and squares are 0,1,2,4 (recall Fermat's little theorem $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$).  So 1-cubes are 0,1 or 2 you see  the only square=1-cube are coming from $(x^3,y^2)=(0,1), (1,0), (-1,2)$, hence there are $1\times 2+3\times 1+3\times 2=11$ points.

Comment: You’re counting the number of times $1-m^3$ is a square modulo $7$, as $0\le m<7$. For each of those seven tests of $m$, you can apply Quadratic Reciprocity to get your answer quickly. For small moduli like seven, though, I just do it by inspection. After all, the only squares are $0,1,2,4$. And while I’m at it, I should recommend strongly to you that for small primes ($\le37$,  I suppose), you should find a generator of the multiplicative group and write down all the powers, in order. You now have a logarithm table to use for quick multiplication.